# Subset using Backtracking

Tags: c

The following question I was asked to solve using backtracking:
It's supposed to return the length of the longest subset of differences that replaces a sign.
For example:
for this given series [11,6,7,8,9] it returns 3.
because it includes this subset [11,8,9] and [11,6,8] .

*In this series a:[11,8,9] a[1]-a[0]<0 and a[2]-a[1]>0 .In other words the sign of the difference between each neighbor changes. *

I pretty much finished the coding but have no idea how to return the max length using backtracking.

Any note/help will be highly appreciated.

```
/* this function checks if we can add another number to the sequence
   and still the differences between the numbers replace a sign.It's enough
   to check the last two*/
int check_rec(int series[],int arr[],int n)
{ int count=0,c=n;
  int temp1=0,temp2=0;
    while(c>=0 && count!=2)
    {
        if (arr[c]==1 && count==0)
        { temp1=series[c];
          count++;
        }
        if (arr[c]==1 && count==1 )
        { temp1=series[c];
          count++;
        }
        c--;
    }
    if(count<2) return 1;
    if(temp1>temp2 && series[n+1] < temp1) return 1;
    if(temp1<temp2 && series[n+1]> temp1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int count_ones(int arr[],int n)
{   int c;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i])
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
    // 1 in the array helper indicates that the index has been chosen.
    void max_crazy(int series[], int n,int helper[],int length,int max[])
{
    if(n==0)
         {
            int x=count_ones(helper,n);
            if(x>max[0])
                max[0]=x;
             }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if(n!=length && i==1 && !check_rec(series,helper,length-n))
           continue;

        helper[0]=i;
        max_crazy(series,n-1,helper+1,length,max);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem description and the examples.

Comment: For example in this series a:[11,8,9]  a[1]-a[0]<0 and a[2]-a[1]>0 .In other words the sign of the difference between each neighbor changes.

Comment: Better?@EugeneSh.

Comment: Yes, a bit clearer.

Comment: What if a certain difference is zero?

Comment: And do you have to use C necessarily? Working with containers like List in C++ or Java will make it so much easier

Answer (score 0):

you can send a pointer that saves the max in the recursive function , and every time you reach the if(n==0) you have to check if the count_ones bigger than max then max=count_ones

Comment: How do I know when to stop it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This answer might be a little clearer if you made it a description along with a few lines of code .